# What does the demon want to do in two scenes in "Becoming"?

Tags: plot-explanation, becoming

In [*Becoming*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2573372/) (2020), in the first scene when Alex just gets possessed and goes out for a ride and outside a store, another person thinks he is Alex too. Why does the demon inside Alex try to control that person to make trouble to Alex?

In another scene, Alex and Lisa go inside a parking area and suddenly another person who sound the same as Alex appears. Since the demon just wants​ to replace Alex's spirit to become a good husband and dad, then why does it control that person to terrify Lisa?

Does this mean that there is some bug in the demon that it can't control itself sometimes and part of it "leaks" into someone nearby?